# Converting multiple UPDATEs in a FOR..LOOP to a single SELECT/UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I'd like to optimize the following PL/SQL statement to a single `SELECT+UPDATE` SQL statement, if possible.

```
--Key is a VARCHAR2, Value is a CLOB
FOR Pair IN (select Key, Value from PairTable) 
LOOP           
  update UpdatableTable
  set CLOBColumn = CLOBColumn || Pair.Value
  where ID in
    (select ID from UpdatableTable
    where CONTAINS("indexedcolumns", '{' || Pair.Key || '}') > 0); 
  commit;
END LOOP;
```

The problem is that I need to use a part of result from the `UPDATE`'s `WHERE` clause in the same `UPDATE`'s `SET` clause. Conceptually, I want to first `SELECT` all of the IDs in the `PairTable`. Then use the `Key` string to see if it's contained in the `UpdatableTable`. Then set the `Value` string (that corresponds with the aforementioned `Key` string) to the `UpdatableTable`'s `CLOBColumn`.

Answer (score 1):

At least use a `FORALL` in PLSQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use the below update statements

update UpdatableTable
  set CLOBColumn = CLOBColumn || Value from PairTable
  where ID in
    (select ID from UpdatableTable
    where CONTAINS("indexedcolumns", '{' || Pair.Key || '}') > 0); 

or

update UpdatableTable
  set CLOBColumn = CLOBColumn || b.Value from  (select Key, Value from PairTable) b
  where ID in
    (select ID from UpdatableTable
    where CONTAINS("indexedcolumns", '{' || Pair.Key || '}') > 0);
```

Comment: Apart from getting a "SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended", I'm unsure whether the correct `Value` will be set. It should have the same ID as the `Key` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It may be with CONTAINS Clause, check the syntax of that CONTAINS index how to use.